# Centering background color via css

Tags: html, css

I have a centered image in the background, but I need my main background-color to stretch as much as the image and stay at the center.

Here is the css for body background

```
body{padding:0; margin:0; background:url(/b.jpg) center 10px no-repeat;}
```

Here is the css for main background

```
.main{background:#4e4645;}
```

Ive tried background-position and margin percents with no luck.

Comment: Show your html too please.

Comment: @BillyMoat its just simple <body>... <div class=main> ... </div></body>

Comment: As @Jack Allen requests, can you show us a picture of how it looks right now and how you want it to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin: 0 auto` to center your `.main` div within the body. Then all you need to do is set the width of `.main` to be equal to the width of your body's background image.

```
.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  background: #4e4645;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/uc56T/1/).

Comment: @JeftLebowski Just to say that if you wanted a fluid answer where the background expands to meet the changing size of the image, see below.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/aX24s/1/

In the example I'm using two background colours, obviously substitute an image in. I've put 50% opacity on the inner div to show that they're both exactly matched in size (one block is bright green, one is red, so the colours mix).

You have the two backgrounds the same size and overlaid exactly.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="outer_div">
        <div class="inner_div">
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.outer_div {
    width:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#dd0000;
}

.inner_div {
    background:#00dd00;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.5;
    height:100%;
}
```